# Ember Buffer Keyword

Tags: ember.js, get, buffer, ember-data

The following Ember code returns "<" symbol.

```
{{{get buffer.buffer.[0]}}}
```

Can someone explain me how it returns "<" symbol and is there any documents or cheat codes to return different other symbols ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what is the value of buffer?

Comment: What's the version of ember you're using? Can you provide an ember twiddle (https://ember-twiddle.com/) which demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Why have you got triple curly braces instead of double?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to access the first element of `buffer.buffer` which is an array?

Try `get buffer.buffer 0` or for older versions of Ember `get buffer.buffer "0"`.

Also worth a try is `buffer.buffer.firstObject`.

There is a discussion on accessing elements of an array in templates here https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/using-array-indices-in-ember-template/13148?u=caltor